# Randomize questions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC site that is an online test site.
I have a question in the admin repository panel. I want these questions to be asked randomly to the user and the result to be stored in a database. please help

Comment: What's your data store for the questions?

Comment: entity framework _ CodeFirst

Comment: What have you tried? You will typically get more helpful answers if you show things you've tried that haven't worked first.

Comment: Use the [Random class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty sort can be done using GUIDs. This can be accomplished in a View Model (Recommended) or within the entity with a `[NotMapped]` column.

For example, given an entity like:

```
public class Question 
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set;} 
}

// View Model
[Serializable]
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set;} 
    public Guid SortKey { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Then when loading you view models:

```
var questions = context.Questions
    .Select(x => new QuestionViewModel
    {
        QuestionId = x.QuestionId,
        QuestionText = x.QuestionText
    }).ToList();

return questions.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey);
```

You can accomplish this with a `[NotMapped]` SortKey in the entity definition (No Database Column) but if you take that approach you will need to materialize the query with `ToList` *before* applying the sort. Otherwise EF will expect a SortKey column to exist in the database in order to translate to SQL.

```
// Entity
public class Question 
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set;} 
    [NotMapped]
    public Guid SortKey { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}


var questions = context.Questions
    .ToList() // Load all questions into memory.
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey);
```

If you were to do:

```
var questions = context.Questions
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
    .ToList();
```

EF would raise an exception as SortKey isn't a mapped column in the DB. We wouldn't want it in the DB because the "random" order would be the same every time the list was read.

The view model approach is recommended to avoid needing to remember rules like this about columns in the entity definition. It also makes it easier to work with where you don't necessarily want to load *everything* about a Question and related details into memory to apply a sort and then maybe only need a handful of values to pass to the view.

Comment: Do you have a project on this?

Comment: No, but you should. :) The above should be enough to apply to your project to update where/how you are loading your questions and be able to load them in a random-like manner..